# addEventListener in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that can toggle whether a div position is fixed or static when another element is clicked.

I am having a problem with `addActionListener`. This is what I have so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LhAc/)

Where have I gone wrong?

The id and class I have used in the html section are based on the site I am making the extension for. I am adding an empty div to `div.spacer` so that I can use it as my toggle button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggle()` will call the function, you want do add it as a listener however. So you want to pass the function as a parameter, like this:

```
tog.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

The other problem is that you have a variable named `toggle` that replaces the function. You have to consider that the function declaration `function toggle() {}` is essentially the same as `var toggle = function() {}` - you declare a variable with the name `toggle` and assign a function to it. You cannot have a "normal" variable with the same name. Rename the variable and all will be fine.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2LhAc/1/)